# Why registerForActivityResult is not available in AppCompatActivity?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I believe I've latest dependencies and gradle. When I extend my Activity (ProfileActivity) from `AppCompatActivity` and try to access `registerForActivityResult` like this -

```
// not working
private val pickSingleImageLauncher =
    registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia()) { // my code }
```

Getting error `Unresolved reference: registerForActivityResult`

I can solve this issue by extending `ComponentActivity` instead `AppCompatActivity` but since I also need to use `supportFragmentManager`. And error goes vice-versa

So How can I use both in my Activity (ProfileActivity.kt)

I've the following `build.gradle (:app)`

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}

android {
   ...
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.0'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.1'
    implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.6.1"
    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.5.4"
}
```

And this is `build.gradle (MyApp)`

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.10' apply false
}
```

So far I know that `AppCompatActivity` extend `FragmentActivity` which extend `ComponentActivity`

I think there are 2 types `ComponentActivity` so these things are confusing don't you think!

Any help will always be appreciated!

Comment: Did you resolve this?